# Colorscheme in nvim won't save

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim

So im like new to linux, just downloaded **Pop!_OS** and i installed **Neovim**, i installed **Vim-Plug** and added a colorscheme, i saved it and ran the file, the theme works, but whenever i close out of **nvim** and reopen it, the colorscheme goes back to default. How do i fix this? i've been frustrated for the past hour. Any help is appreciated.

My **init.vim** file

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'fcpg/vim-fahrenheit'
call plug#end()


colorscheme fahrenheit
```

Comment: `:colorScheme <name>`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, when I use
`:source %`
inside `init.vim`: the theme is applied, but stops working after closing, my `init.vim` in that section was this

```
colorscheme synthwave84
set termguicolors
```

I have noticed that `termguicolors` helps many theme plugins. But I had it, so experimenting I noticed that order matters

Then I modified based on other similars `init.vim`

```
set termguicolors
set background=dark
colorscheme synthwave84
```

Here some Images of order,
[no theme, termguicolors before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYYx1.png)
[theme working, and saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daYjN.png)

So in conclusion, try this, and tell me how it goes

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'fcpg/vim-fahrenheit'
call plug#end()

set termguicolors
colorscheme fahrenheit
```